# Create Shortcut Function in T-SQL

Tags: sql, function, t-sql

Using the code below I can create a comma separated list of results from the results of a select statement:

```
DECLARE @lst NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @lst = COALESCE(NULLIF(@lst,'')+N',',N'') +  [colName]
FROM [tableName]
```

I would like to transform this into a sort of *shortcut* function, for example:

```
SELECT dbo.fnColAsList([colName]) 
FROM [tableName]
```

Is this at all possible?

---

**Edit:**

To give an example, if the select statement returned the following 3 columns:

```
SELECT [colName] FROM [tableName]

>>>  colName
     -----------
[1]  foo1
[2]  foo2
[3]  foo3
```

Then the code would produce a single varchar field:

```
SELECT @lst = COALESCE(NULLIF(@lst,'')+N',',N'') + [colName] 
FROM [tableName];
SELECT @lst

>>> lst
    ---------
[1] foo1,foo2,foo3
```

I wish to produce a shortcut so that I can call the code around any column so for example I could do this:

```
SELECT fnColAsList(colName) AS 'x' FROM [tab1];

>>>  x
     -----------------
[1]  tab1Col1,tab1Col2,tab1Coln


SELECT fnColAsList(colName) AS 'y' FROM [tab2];

>>>  y
     -----------------
[1]  tab2Col1,tab2Col2,tab2Coln
```

---

**Answered:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnColAsList(@rawxml XML)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
RETURN STUFF(((SELECT ',' + AllAttribs.value(N'.','nvarchar(max)')
               FROM @rawxml.nodes('/row/@*') x (AllAttribs)
               FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('x'),TYPE).value('/x[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') 
              ),1,1,'');
END
GO

SELECT dbo.fnColAsList((SELECT [colName] FROM tabName FOR XML RAW))
```

Comment: There may be a way, but you should probably stop and ask yourself why you're doing this. SQL Server has types *designed* for holding multiple values (tables and the XML data type). So ask yourself why you're not using those and are instead cramming data into a string. Particularly in a language which generally has poor support for string manipulation. And your original code is *potentially* faulty - SQL Server does not guarantee that it will perform that variable assignment exactly once for each row in the table.

Comment: It's out of my hands unfortunately due to not having control over the environment I am working in. The procedures where I require this use comma-delimited strings as variable arguments which are passed into a split-string table-value function to generate a one-column table. These lists are normally generated in separate queries within SSRS. I want to use this approach simply for testing reasons to generate a comma-delimited list for testing values when designing / maintaining procs. As such validation is not required as I will only use this on varchar fields.

Comment: I don't know if I get this correctly: Are you looking for a function to return **a row** of a result separated (something like a *CSV-engine*) or are you looking for a function like MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT` to get the result of a group / sub-select as a csv-column?

Comment: @Shnugo - I will put an example above to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a trick: Pass in the SELECT as XML by wrapping it in paranthesis. XML is - other than pure SQL - much mightier in dealing with generic names:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TestCSV(@SelectForXMLRaw XML)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN STUFF(
                 (
                    SELECT ',' + AllAttribs.value(N'.','nvarchar(max)')
                    FROM @SelectForXMLRaw.nodes('/row/@*') x(AllAttribs)
                    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
                 ).value(N'.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,''
                );
END
GO

DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,col1 VARCHAR(100),col2 VARCHAR(100),col3 VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('1a','2a','3a'),('1b','2b','3b');

SELECT ID
      ,dbo.TestCSV((SELECT * FROM @tbl AS t2 WHERE t2.ID=t.ID FOR XML RAW)) AS Concatenated
FROM @tbl AS t
GO

DROP FUNCTION dbo.TestCSV;
```

The result

```
ID  Concatenated
1   1,1a,2a,3a
2   2,1b,2b,3b
```

### UPDATE According to your edits

From you edits I take, that you need this for *row-wise* data. You can achieve this with the same function actually. Just try this

```
DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE(SomeUnknownColumn VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES ('Val 1'),('Val 2'),('Val 3');

SELECT dbo.TestCSV((SELECT * FROM @tbl2 FOR XML RAW)) AS Concatenated
```

Thne result:

```
Val 1,Val 2,Val 3
```

Comment: Just what I was after, I edited it somewhat as your version doesn't account for special characters: FROM @SelectForXMLRaw.nodes('/row/@*') x (AllAttribs)
                    FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('x'),TYPE).value('/x[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'

Comment: @JamieStuartRobinParsons True, I just edited my answer to reflect this...